# Is there a short way in python to assign non-empty values to dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a shorter way of writing this code to avoid using ifs for every check?

```
first_name = "John"
middle_name = ""
last_name = "Doe"

data = {}

if first_name:
  data['first_name'] = first_name
if middle_name:
  data['middle_name'] = middle_name
if last_name:
  data['last_name'] = last_name

return data
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first assign all values without checking for truthiness, and then filter afterwards:

```
data = {
    "first_name": first_name,
    "middle_name": middle_name,
    "last_name": last_name,
}
data = {key: value for key, value in data.items() if value}
```

But given that you're storing/processing names: I recommend just using a single variable for the entire name. [Whatever you're assuming about names is likely wrong](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).